# When making an iPhone App in Xcode, how do you make an app icon WITHOUT the phone adding the default glass effect glare?

Tags: iphone, xcode, icons

I've seen many apps in the app store who's icons on the iPhone Springboard do not have the default rounded corners and "glass effect" that are created by default when I just add a 57x57 png to my resources and specify it in the plist. Does anyone know how to NOT get the iPhone to add the attributes to my application icon image when I compile and load it on the iPhone?

Answer (score 10):

If you go edit your info.plist file, there is a property called UIPrerenderedIcon, it'll be set to false, if you change it to true, the phone won't process your icon before displaying it. You'll also have to round the corners yourself as well I believe.

take a look at: http://iosdevelopertips.com/general/remove-shine-gloss-effect-on-iphone-icon.html

Answer (score 4):

It's all in what you search for:  flat iphone icon

Add this to info.plist:

UIPrerenderedIcon : true

Brandon might appreciate a thank you: http://blog.quazie.net/2009/05/flat-iphone-icon-aka-get-rid-of-icon-shine/

Answer (score 3):

Set `UIPrerenderedIcon` in your `info.plist` to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

As a key in plist this is now "Icon already includes gloss effects" YES or NO, where if your select YES XCode does not apply the gloss effect..